# Compile C++ Class based on MFC as Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc, libraries

I've implemented a C++ Class depends on MFC class. Now I would like to create a library to use my Class in other programs. 
Using VisualStudio2015 I've tried to use "Win32 Projects" and "DLL MFC" without any resoults.

Any one can help me about it?

Thanks

Comment: "I've tried to use" means what exactly?  "without any resoults" means what exactly?  Actual errors, what you expected to happen, etc.  Concrete details.

Comment: Choose DLL in place of exe in the output type to build a dynamic library or LIB to build a static library for distribution to others.

Comment: Your question is vague. Were you able to create the DLL or are you facing issues while using the DLL? What steps you followed? Give some code snippet.

Comment: @seccpur: Using MFC in a library requires a lot more than setting the linker's output type.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from any type of project (they are just a shortcut to the right property setting).

You just have to set the right property.

In the property page go to `General->Configuration Type` and select one option between `.dll` and `.lib`, depending on the type of library you want to create.

Comment: Using MFC in a library is **way** more involved than producing a DLL or static library. I'm afraid, this answer isn't very helpful. It's usually best not trying to answer a poor question to begin with.